# Angular module federation on azure app service

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, webpack-module-federation

I’m creating a website with webpack federation module. For this I have 3 projects out of 3 different git repos. So I have 3 here in azure devops. My question is how to deploy the 3 projects on the same app service but with 1 pipeline per project
Among these 3 projects, I will have 1 that will be exposed on the web and the other 2 will not be exposed directly

Answer (score 0):

Using azure devops portal you can deploy multiple pipelines.

While deploying you have to add a task of deploying the project in a specific app service.

To do this first click on the app service deploy
[image]

then fill the form and add the task.

[image]

Thus, while creating multiple pipelines for each of your projects each time you can select the same app service.

refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) for further explanation.